# Make an order form that selects items by category then puts them in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Im trying to make an order form that selects items by category then puts the items in a list. I cant seem to figure out how to add multiple items to the list. This is my first time asking a question here and Im a noob when it comes to javascript. I have managed to add one item to the list but cannot figure out how to add more items to the other textboxes. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allOptions = $('#selectprod option')
  $('#selectcat').change(function() {
    $('#selectprod option').remove()
    var classN = $('#selectcat option:selected').prop('class');
    var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);
    $.each(opts, function(i, j) {
      $(j).appendTo('#selectprod');
    });
  });
});

var select = document.getElementById('selectprod'),
  input = document.getElementById('textbox');


select.onchange = function() {
  input.value = this.value;
};

select.onchange();
```

```css
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prodselectbox">
  <div class="floatleft cat">Category &nbsp;</div>
  <div class="floatleft catid">
    <select id="selectcat" name="categoryselected">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Category</option>
            <option class="fruit" value="Fruit" id="selectionone">Fruit</option>
            <option class="veggies" value="Vegetables" id="selectiontwo">Vegetables</option>
            <option class="meat" value="Meat" id="selectionthree">Meat</option>
  
        </select>
  </div>

  <div class="floatleft artid" style="margin-left:20px;">Product &nbsp; </div>
  <div class="floatleft selectarticle">
    <select id="selectprod" name="articleID">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Product</option>
            <option value="Apples" class="selectors edibles">Apples</option>
            <option value="Oranges" class="selectors fruit">Oranges</option>
            <option value="Grapes" class="selectors fruit">Grapes</option>
            <option value="Strawberries" class="selectors fruit">Strawberries</option>
            <option value="Pears" class="selectors fruit">Pears</option>
            <option value="Blackberries" class="selectors fruit">Blackberries</option>
            <option value="Peaches" class="selectors fruit">Peaches</option>
            <option value="Spinach" class="selectors veggies">Spinach</option>
            <option value="Potatoes" class="selectors veggies">Potatoes</option>
            <option value="Kale" class="selectors veggies">Kale</option>
            <option value="Carrots" class="selectors veggies">Carrots</option>
            <option value="Acorn-squash" class="selectors veggies">Acorn Squash</option>
                    <option value="Chicken" class="selectors meat">Chicken</option>
  <option value="Beef" class="selectors meat">Beef</option>
     <option value="Pork" class="selectors meat">Pork</option>
    <option value="Fish" class="selectors meat">Fish</option>

        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:50px;">
  <p>Item 1:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an array of all the inputs and **circle** through it.

Also, I would add a `Select Product` option on the `#selectprod` combo back, and make it be selected by default.

Finally, I would automatically re-select `Select Product` when a user picks a product, so they are able to select again the same product (this is achieved by the `reset combo[2]` line below - which can, of course, be removed).

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allOptions = $('#selectprod option')
  $('#selectcat').change(function() {
    $('#selectprod option').remove()
    var classN = $('#selectcat option:selected').prop('class');
    var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);
    allOptions.filter('.piths').appendTo('#selectprod');    // add 'Select Product'
    $.each(opts, function(i, j) {
      $(j).appendTo('#selectprod');
    });
    $('#selectprod').find('.piths').prop('selected', true); // reset combo
  });
});

var select = document.getElementById('selectprod');
  inputs = $('#textbox').add('#textbox2').add('#textbox3'), // create array of inputs
  currentInput = 0;                                         // index to keep track


select.onchange = function() {
  inputs[currentInput].value = this.value;                  // set value of curernt
  currentInput = (currentInput + 1) % inputs.length;        // increment index (circle)
  $('#selectprod').find('.piths').prop('selected', true);   // reset combo[2]
};
```

```css
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prodselectbox">
  <div class="floatleft cat">Category &nbsp;</div>
  <div class="floatleft catid">
    <select id="selectcat" name="categoryselected">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Category</option>
            <option class="fruit" value="Fruit" id="selectionone">Fruit</option>
            <option class="veggies" value="Vegetables" id="selectiontwo">Vegetables</option>
            <option class="meat" value="Meat" id="selectionthree">Meat</option>
  
        </select>
  </div>

  <div class="floatleft artid" style="margin-left:20px;">Product &nbsp; </div>
  <div class="floatleft selectarticle">
    <select id="selectprod" name="articleID">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Product</option>
            <option value="Apples" class="selectors edibles">Apples</option>
            <option value="Oranges" class="selectors fruit">Oranges</option>
            <option value="Grapes" class="selectors fruit">Grapes</option>
            <option value="Strawberries" class="selectors fruit">Strawberries</option>
            <option value="Pears" class="selectors fruit">Pears</option>
            <option value="Blackberries" class="selectors fruit">Blackberries</option>
            <option value="Peaches" class="selectors fruit">Peaches</option>
            <option value="Spinach" class="selectors veggies">Spinach</option>
            <option value="Potatoes" class="selectors veggies">Potatoes</option>
            <option value="Kale" class="selectors veggies">Kale</option>
            <option value="Carrots" class="selectors veggies">Carrots</option>
            <option value="Acorn-squash" class="selectors veggies">Acorn Squash</option>
                    <option value="Chicken" class="selectors meat">Chicken</option>
  <option value="Beef" class="selectors meat">Beef</option>
     <option value="Pork" class="selectors meat">Pork</option>
    <option value="Fish" class="selectors meat">Fish</option>

        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:50px;">
  <p>Item 1:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer works just the way I want. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: Great to know! You can accept it to let us know is worked: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allOptions = $('#selectprod option')
  $('#selectcat').change(function() {
    $('#selectprod option').remove()
    var classN = $('#selectcat option:selected').prop('class');
    var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);
    $.each(opts, function(i, j) {
      $(j).appendTo('#selectprod');
    });
  });
});

var select = document.getElementById('selectprod'),
  count = 1;
  
  


select.onchange = function() {
  input = document.getElementById('textbox'+ count);
  input.value = this.value;
  count++;
};
```

```css
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prodselectbox">
  <div class="floatleft cat">Category &nbsp;</div>
  <div class="floatleft catid">
    <select id="selectcat" name="categoryselected">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Category</option>
            <option class="fruit" value="Fruit" id="selectionone">Fruit</option>
            <option class="veggies" value="Vegetables" id="selectiontwo">Vegetables</option>
            <option class="meat" value="Meat" id="selectionthree">Meat</option>
  
        </select>
  </div>

  <div class="floatleft artid" style="margin-left:20px;">Product &nbsp; </div>
  <div class="floatleft selectarticle">
    <select id="selectprod" name="articleID">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Product</option>
            <option value="Apples" class="selectors edibles">Apples</option>
            <option value="Oranges" class="selectors fruit">Oranges</option>
            <option value="Grapes" class="selectors fruit">Grapes</option>
            <option value="Strawberries" class="selectors fruit">Strawberries</option>
            <option value="Pears" class="selectors fruit">Pears</option>
            <option value="Blackberries" class="selectors fruit">Blackberries</option>
            <option value="Peaches" class="selectors fruit">Peaches</option>
            <option value="Spinach" class="selectors veggies">Spinach</option>
            <option value="Potatoes" class="selectors veggies">Potatoes</option>
            <option value="Kale" class="selectors veggies">Kale</option>
            <option value="Carrots" class="selectors veggies">Carrots</option>
            <option value="Acorn-squash" class="selectors veggies">Acorn Squash</option>
                    <option value="Chicken" class="selectors meat">Chicken</option>
  <option value="Beef" class="selectors meat">Beef</option>
     <option value="Pork" class="selectors meat">Pork</option>
    <option value="Fish" class="selectors meat">Fish</option>

        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:50px;">
  <p>Item 1:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox1"  class="selected_item" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" class="selected_item" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox3"  class="selected_item" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

find an input with `value == ""` and change its value into what you selected

no counter needed, so you can clear one input and select whatever you want again

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allOptions = $('#selectprod option')
  $('#selectcat').change(function() {
    $('#selectprod option').remove()
    var classN = $('#selectcat option:selected').prop('class');
    var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);
    $.each(opts, function(i, j) {
      $(j).appendTo('#selectprod');
    });
  });
});

var select = document.getElementById('selectprod');

select.onchange = function() {
    var input = $('input[id^="textbox"]').get().find(x=>$(x).val() == "");
    if(input){
        $(input).val(this.value);
    }
};

select.onchange();
```

```css
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prodselectbox">
  <div class="floatleft cat">Category &nbsp;</div>
  <div class="floatleft catid">
    <select id="selectcat" name="categoryselected">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Category</option>
            <option class="fruit" value="Fruit" id="selectionone">Fruit</option>
            <option class="veggies" value="Vegetables" id="selectiontwo">Vegetables</option>
            <option class="meat" value="Meat" id="selectionthree">Meat</option>
  
        </select>
  </div>

  <div class="floatleft artid" style="margin-left:20px;">Product &nbsp; </div>
  <div class="floatleft selectarticle">
    <select id="selectprod" name="articleID">
            <option value="" class="piths">Select Product</option>
            <option value="Apples" class="selectors edibles">Apples</option>
            <option value="Oranges" class="selectors fruit">Oranges</option>
            <option value="Grapes" class="selectors fruit">Grapes</option>
            <option value="Strawberries" class="selectors fruit">Strawberries</option>
            <option value="Pears" class="selectors fruit">Pears</option>
            <option value="Blackberries" class="selectors fruit">Blackberries</option>
            <option value="Peaches" class="selectors fruit">Peaches</option>
            <option value="Spinach" class="selectors veggies">Spinach</option>
            <option value="Potatoes" class="selectors veggies">Potatoes</option>
            <option value="Kale" class="selectors veggies">Kale</option>
            <option value="Carrots" class="selectors veggies">Carrots</option>
            <option value="Acorn-squash" class="selectors veggies">Acorn Squash</option>
                    <option value="Chicken" class="selectors meat">Chicken</option>
  <option value="Beef" class="selectors meat">Beef</option>
     <option value="Pork" class="selectors meat">Pork</option>
    <option value="Fish" class="selectors meat">Fish</option>

        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:50px;">
  <p>Item 1:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" /></p>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
  <p>Item 2:Add this to my list:
    <input type="text" id="textbox3" /></p>
</div>
```